# Yahoo Mail returns error #MBR100 to POP3 mail client Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, pop3, yahoo-mail

Attempting to fetch mail from a Yahoo Mail account with Thunderbird using POP3 settings causes the following error to be seen in the mail client:

> Sending of password for user *<email address>* did not succeed. Mail server pop.mail.yahoo.com responded: (#MBR100)

Logging into the Yahoo Mail web page with this same password works fine, so the problem is not an incorrect password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cause of this error is a password which is too long. A password with a length of thirty characters is known to be fine, but using a password of more than thirty-two characters in length is known to lead to this error.

Use the Yahoo website to change your password to something of thirty characters or less, update Thunderbird to use the new password, and you should immediately be able to retrieve Yahoo Mail using Thunderbird.